# How to import term set with Use this Term Set for Site Navigation property selected using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, 2013, managed-metadata-service

```
$session = Get-SPTaxonomySession -Site $sitename
$termStore = $session.TermStores[“Managed Metadata Application”]
$group = $termstore.CreateGroup(“My New Group”)
$group.Description = "My Term Group"
$termStore.CommitAll()
$termSet = $group.CreateTermSet(“My TermSet”,1033)
$termSet.Description = “My TermSet”
$termSet.IsAvailableForTagging = $true
$termSet.IsOpenForTermCreation = $true
$termStore.CommitAll()
```

Here like $termSet.IsAvailableForTagging I want to enable  "Use this Term Set for Site Navigation" using powershell.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I achieved it with following code.

```
 $navigationSet = $group.CreateTermSet($termsetName)
 $navigationSet.SetCustomProperty("_Sys_Nav_IsNavigationTermSet", "True")
 $navigationSet.SetCustomProperty("_Sys_Nav_AttachedWeb_SiteId", $site.ID.ToString())
 $navigationSet.SetCustomProperty("_Sys_Nav_AttachedWeb_WebId", $site.RootWeb.ID.ToString())    
 $navigationSet.SetCustomProperty("_Sys_Nav_AttachedWeb_OriginalUrl", $site.RootWeb.Url )
```

Answer (score 2):

You do this in powershell by converting the TermSet to a NavigationTermSet

```
$site = Get-SPSite -Identity $sitename 
$navTermSet = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Navigation.NavigationTermSet]::GetAsResolvedByWeb($termSet, $site.RootWeb, "GlobalNavigationTaxonomyProvider");
```

Now you have access to the navigation term set object in powershell and can use it like in [oldbam's answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/58746/10084)

Comment: Not interested in OP's question at all but man I've been looking for these two lines of code all over the place. Thank you so much. Do you have sites giving more details about taxonomy in powershell? +1

Comment: @Ergec I am a developer so I often transpose C# into powershell to quickly test things out.  That being said here are some sites that I trust that often have SharePoint and Powershell posts;
[Karine Bosch](http://karinebosch.wordpress.com/2013/12/13), 
[Todd Klindt](http://www.toddklindt.com/default.aspx), 
[Wictor Wilen](http://www.wictorwilen.se/), 
[Spencer Harbar](http://www.harbar.net/default.aspx), and 
[Andrew Connell](http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog). Hope you find those useful.

Answer (score 0):

This code should help you:

```
     // Obtain navigation term set
     NavigationTermSet navigationTermSet = NavigationTermSet.GetAsResolvedByWeb(termSet, web, "GlobalNavigationTaxonomyProvider");
     // Specify that this term set can be used for site navigation
     navigationTermSet.IsNavigationTermSet = true;
     // specify target page for all terms in this term set 
     navigationTermSet.TargetUrlForChildTerms.Value = "~site/Pages/Topics/Topic.aspx";
```

Comment: How to obtain the same in powershell?